# Android - Text not displayed in TextView in spite of (apparently) working setView

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am working on an application which needs to retrieve some informations from the user and I am using Fragments to do that. The idea is to have a ListFragment that displays the name of different Fragments that allow the user to give informations, when user click on one name in the ListFragment, the corresponding fragment is displayed in full screen if we are in portrait mode or next the ListFragment in landscape mode.

As basis I used the code explained and given in the following links:
[google fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [Dynamic Layouts using the Fragment Manager](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture09/lecture09.html).

I "slightly" modified the code of the links above to have two TextView in the Fragment used to retrieved informations. I am trying to retain states for this Fragment. I tried to set **setRetainInstance** to true but it does not work so I am trying with **onSaveInstanceState**.

In **onSaveInstanceState** I put the content of the TextView in a bundle and in **onCreateView** if savedInstanceState is not null then I retrieve the strings to be displayed in the TextView. I can see in debug mode that everything (seems to) work, after onSaveInstanceState the Bundle has the strings and in onCreateView the strings are correctly retrieved and pass to the TextView with setView but at the end the TextView remain empty.

Why does that happens? How can that happen?

Below the code of my fragment:

```
public class DataFragment extends AbstractFragment {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private View mView;
    private TextView mFirstNameTextView = null;
    private TextView mMailTextView = null;

    Bundle mArgs;

    public DataFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setRetainInstance(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_fragment, container, false);

        mFirstNameTextView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.setting_Firstname);
        mMailTextView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.setting_Mail);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            String test = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
            String retest = savedInstanceState.getString("mail");

            mFirstNameTextView.setText(test);
            mMailTextView.setText(retest);
        }
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        String test = mFirstNameTextView.getText().toString();
        String testmail = mMailTextView.getText().toString();

        outState.putString("name", mFirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("mail", mMailTextView.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }    

    @Override
    public int getShownIndex() {
        int ret = getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
        return ret;
    }    
}
```

To be complete this Fragment inherit from AbstractFragment. AbstractFragment as mentioned by its name is an abstract class that inherit from Fragment. I use this class because I plan to have several fragments and this class helps me to write less code. For completeness below is the code for the AbstractFragment:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment {

    public AbstractFragment(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public int getShownIndex(){
        int ret = getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
        return ret;
    }  
}
```

**Edit:**

Just to be clear, the problem is not to retrieve data, the problem is to display data. I am retrieving the values I stored using **onSaveInstanceState** but these values are not displayed in TextView. Below a screenshot of my application with a breakpoint on onSaveInstanceState, this screenshot has been taken after I entre the Strings *"foo"* and *"bar"* in my TextView and then I rotate the AVD, we can see on the screenshot that strings *"foo"* and *"bar"* are inside the savedInstanceState Bundle and the variables test and retest are correctly initialized to *"foo"* and *"bar"*, but these strings are not displayed in the TextView
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing arguments and savedInstanceState. Go through the developer documents [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) to know what is savedInstanceState.

Refer arguments bundle rather than savedInstanceState bundle to make it work proper. Refer the following code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_fragment, container, false);

    mFirstNameTextView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.setting_Firstname);
    mMailTextView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.setting_Mail);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    if (arguments !=null){
        String test = arguments.getString("name");
        String retest = arguments.getString("mail");

        mFirstNameTextView.setText(test);
        mMailTextView.setText(retest);
    }
    else {
        Log.e(DataFragment.class, "Arguments was null, did not load the name and email TextView");
    }

    return mView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but for me the [reference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) you gave confirm what I did. If you look at the section "Save your Activity State" and "Restore Your Activity State" that is exactly what I did